# Using local SSH Keys Inside a Docker Container

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I'm having a problem with using the Local SSH Key inside a docker container, the purpose is to pull the source code in the docker container. After searching on google, I found a few articles with instructions.
https://medium.com/trabe/use-your-local-ssh-keys-inside-a-docker-container-ea1d117515dc

First, I would like to list the parameters I am using:

- MacOS
- Docker compose

=> I have followed using local keys by mounting volumes, then I have 2 problems:

1/ docker-compose run test ssh remoteuser@remotehost.

remoteuser & remotehost what parameters should I use instead

2/ After the group ran away, I was disappointed

- docker-compose run sskkey
- Pulling sskkey (ssh-local:)...
- ERROR: pull access denied for ssh-local, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

If you have any experience with this case, please share it with me. Or if there is a better solution for me, please learn to solve the current problem. I thank you for reading the article.

Comment: Generally the way I'd do this is by checking the `Dockerfile` into the source repository, cloning it on my local system, running `docker build` to create a new image, and then `docker run` a new container based on that new image.  I would not try to update the application or code inside an existing container; just delete it and make a new one.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, tks for your comments. i've found Volume docker which is one i'm looking for